# UIView created programmatically at top of another UIView not working in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm trying to create an UIView programmatically at top of a UIView, but I don't get it to be at top. All the elements from the Interface Builder get at top of this view created programmatically:

This is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

The green square should be at top of this UIScrollView...

viewDidLoad():

```
    var DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 100))
    DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
    DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
    globalView.addSubview(DynamicView)

    view.bringSubviewToFront(DynamicView)
```

Interface Builder:

[image: interface builder]

Answer (score 0):

Try add your subview using `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`, not using `addSubview`. You can specify the z-order this way.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(DynamicView)
```

You need to call bringSubviewToFront on the parent view.